# Fixing damaged text after the fact

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, encoding

Last month I made a scraper for [this](https://www.dizionario-latino.com/) Latin dictionary. It finally finished executing (that website gave me response times of 6 to 8 seconds per page). To bad I find out that a good chunk of my data is severely compromised...
eg. commandūcor ----> command\xc5\xabcor || commandūcāris ----> command\xc5\xabc\xc4\x81ris

I made the stupid mistake of using the str() function on the raw data I got from requests. Just like this:

```
import requests

r = requests.get("https://www.dizionario-latino.com/dizionario-latino-
flessione.php?lemma=COMMANDUCOR100", verify = False)

out = str(r.content)

with open("test.html", 'w') as file:
    file.write(out)
```

I'd really appreciate it if anyone could help me restore the broken text.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you sure it is "broken"

Comment: It is not broken, these are probably just binary strings.

Comment: @ᴡʜᴀᴄᴋᴀᴍᴀᴅᴏᴏᴅʟᴇ3000 Well I can't seem to figure out how to restore it to it's previous state

Comment: Try printing it. And what was its previous state?

Comment: For example it prints: command\xc5\xabcor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`r.content` returns `bytes`. (In contrast, [`r.text` returns a `str`](http://www.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#response-content). The `requests` module attempts to guess the correct decoding based on HTTP headers and decodes the bytes using that encoding for you. In the future maybe that is what you would want to use instead).

If `r.content` contained `bytes` such as `b'command\xc5\xabcor'`, then
`str(r.content)` returns a `str` which begins with the characters `b'` and ends with a literal `'`.

```
In [45]: str(b'command\xc5\xabcor')
Out[45]: "b'command\\xc5\\xabcor'"
```

You can use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html) to recover the bytes:

```
In [46]: ast.literal_eval(str(b'command\xc5\xabcor'))
Out[46]: b'command\xc5\xabcor'
```

You could then decode these `bytes` to a `str`. The URL you posted declares the content is UTF-8 encoded:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

Assuming all the data you downloaded uses the same encoding, you could recover the content as a str by calling the `bytes.decode('utf-8')` method:

```
In [47]: ast.literal_eval(str(b'command\xc5\xabcor')).decode('utf-8')
Out[47]: 'commandūcor'
```

---

```
import ast
import requests

r = requests.get("https://www.dizionario-latino.com/dizionario-latino-flessione.php?lemma=COMMANDUCOR100", verify = False)

out = str(r.content)

with open("test.html", 'w') as file:
    file.write(out)

with open("test.html", 'r') as f_in, open("test-fixed.html", 'w') as f_out:
    broken_text = f_in.read()  
    content = ast.literal_eval(broken_text)
    assert content == r.content
    text = content.decode('utf-8')
    f_out.write(text)
```

Answer (score 4):

Just [`.decode`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode) them using `utf-8` (the default). You can read more about character encodings in Python's [Unicode howto](https://docs.python.org/3.6/howto/unicode.html).

```
b'command\xc5\xabcor'.decode()  # 'commandūcor'
b'command\xc5\xabc\xc4\x81ris'.decode()  # 'commandūcāris'
```

Comment: Thank you, That works! How would I implement this? If I say b = "command\xc5\xabcor" print(b.encode().decode()) I get "commandÅ«cor" as an output which is incorrect

Comment: @AlexP. Interesting... You're wanting to treat a string as though it were bytes. I don't know. You might want to ask this in a new question for more visibility.

Comment: Why do you `endcode().decode()`? That would be a round-trip but apparently you should specify the correct encoding explicitly to avoid getting mojibake.